# How do I create a memory dump of my computer freeze or crash?

Tags: windows, freeze, crash, minidumps, community-faq-proposed

As a lot of us encounter freezes or crashes, I am wondering how do I manually initiate a computer to freeze in order to create a memory dump to view and diagnose any issues that may be involved with the crash?

I am looking on how to ***force*** the computer to crash instead of waiting for the computer to do it itself.

Comment: Forcing it to crash won't help diagnose the problem, since in order to do so you'd have to already know what was making it crash in the first place, and you could just fix it instead.

Comment: @KenWhite: This is not true. Can you tell me what application, driver or device hangs my computer if I'm looking at the desktop? No! You will need a dump which you can analyze to do so...

Answer (score 18):

Your question is slightly unclear -- do you want to make it generate the dump when it crashes, or do you want to generate a dump when it isn't crashing and try to diagnose it from that? If the latter, that's probably not a particularly good way of going about it.

### Enabling crash dumps

You can enable crash dumps by going to

`My Computer` > `Properties` > `Startup and Recovery` > `Settings`

and then select either a minidump or a kernel memory dump under `Write debugging information`. This should write a minidump when a crash is caught.

### Initiating a manual crash

**Required set-up**

If you're asking how to crash manually and get a minidump written, you can do the following:

1. Open regedit.
2. Locate the following key if you have a USB keyboard:

   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\kbdhid\Parameters`

   Or the following key if you have a PS/2 keyboard:

   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\i8042prt\Parameters`

   In the Edit menu, click Add Value and add the following registry entry:

   - Name: `CrashOnCtrlScroll`
   - Data Type: `REG_DWORD`
   - Value: `1`
3. Exit the registry editor, then reboot.

**Crashing the (hung) system**

After the reboot, you can trigger a crash by pressing the <kbd>SCROLL</kbd> keyboard key twice while you hold the right <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key, as long as you have Windows set to write a dump when doing this, it will write it to `%SYSTEMROOT%\Minidump`.

The hotkey in short form is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SCR LK</kbd>+<kbd>SCR LK</kbd>.

Comment: what about Laptop  ??

Comment: It works on a laptop.

Answer (score 3):

### Dumping a a process when it hangs or crashes

I would use [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) to create a dump of the proccess that is crashed:

[ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) is a command-line utility whose primary purpose is monitoring an application for CPU spikes and generating crash dumps during a spike that an administrator or developer can use to determine the cause of the spike. ProcDump also includes hung window monitoring (using the same definition of a window hang that Windows and Task Manager use), unhandled exception monitoring and can generate dumps based on the values of system performance counters. It also can serve as a general process dump utility that you can embed in other scripts.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell the computer to make a crash dump when it blue screens in

`My Computer` -> `Properties` -> `Advanced` -> `Start and Recovery`.

### Analyzing the dump

I use [these procedures](http://www.memecode.com/docs/minidump.php) to analyze the dump.

Comment: Dead link 404 not found