# Hibernate & Sleep broken after IE 9 RTM installation in Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, internet-explorer, sleep, hibernate

I have a question about hibernation. I installed Internet Explorer 9 RTM x64 on my Windows 7 x64 SP1 desktop machine. After this, computer don't entry the hibernation or (hybrid) sleep state properly. After I hibernate the computer the monitor become blank screen and the keyboard and mouse are inactive. But the machine is still running and there isn't any possibility to switch them off as only with power button. But this is recognized on next start as ineligible because of log entry with message “The previous system shutdown at xx:xx:xx on ‎xx.‎xx.‎x was unexpected“ and menu with safe mode option.

I’m clearly not sure if it has something to do with Internet Explorer installation, but I’m definitely guaranteed that before of this I never had some problems with hibernation or (hybrid) sleep. In Windows logs isn’t something suspect. I switched the hibernation off and on, installed new drivers for mainboard, graphic and network card, checked the hard disk, nothing was helpful.

This is really sad, beacuse I don't like to switch the computer completely off because it takes longer to boot. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried Windows' System Restore to go back to a point before you installed IE9 to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: +1 @techie007: Could help, but still I don't see how IE9 could have done this... :-S

Comment: It probably didn't (I'd bet money it didn't 'cause' the problem, just revealed it).  That's why she should try the system restore. If it doesn't 'fix' her hibernation problem, then IE9 (and/or whatever else was installed) wasn't the cause.  If it does, then she can step forward again to see if it happens again, and become more aware of a potential culprit, since she'd be paying more attention and taking more steps to get there. :)

Comment: But I don't think it is unlikely. Look in Power Options. After IE9 installation is there new option Internet Explorer. So I think it can have something to do with.

Comment: I can confirm that Windows 7 64bit does stop hibernating after IE9 installation. Installed two days ago and the PC hasn't hibernated since.

Comment: Have you been able to fix this issue? I see no fixes below. Please respond to your own question with your solution if you where able to solve the problem.

Comment: @AzP The issue was "fixed" by "oneself". After couple of months and  windows updates, I'm able to hibernate my computer again, but I don't know the exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, as shown in your comments, you might want to keep it simple and do a System Restore.

If you are familiar with the command line, you could check what devices could cause this.

Type `powercfg /?` to get a list of commands and their help, you'll want to inspect `-DEVICEQUERY`.

Most likely, you'll want to check these options to the above parameter:

```
S1_supported            List devices supporting light sleep.
S2_supported            List devices supporting deeper sleep.
S3_supported            List devices supporting deepest sleep.
S4_supported            List devices supporting hibernation.
```

Also, try to disconnect any devices or hardware from your computer/motherboard that you don't need to see if one of those is preventing your sleep/hibernate; divide and conquer to figure out which device.

Strange that this occurs because of Internet Explorer 9, did you do a proper reboot cycle after setup?

Can you check what happened right before this started happening in:

- The event log.
- The "installed on" dates in Add/Remove Software, also check those for the installed updates.
- The files in your temporary folders around that time. (Start > <kbd>%TEMP%</kbd> > <kbd>ENTER</kbd>)
- The files in your download folders aronud that time.

Also, mention this time and upload the following files so I can inspect them:

- `C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log` (Contains global installation log events)
- `C:\Windows\INF\setupapi.app.log` (Contains driver installation log events)
- `C:\Windows\INF\setupapi.dev.log` (Contains last driver installation log events in detail)
- `C:\Windows\Logs\IE9_NR_Setup.log` (Contains Internet Explorer 9 installation log events)

I haven't tried it before, but maybe you could generate a dump where it hangs so we know why it hangs:

[How do I create a memory dump of my computer freeze or crash?](https://superuser.com/questions/224496/how-do-i-create-a-memory-dump-of-my-computer-freeze-or-crash)

---

> because it takes longer to boot

If it is slow around the login phase you can save a [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) file and upload it too, so I can look into it.

If it is slow during the boot phase and you want to get your hands dirty, see [these questions](https://superuser.com/search?q=xbootmgr).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will check it with the command line parameters. Yes I did proper reboot after IE9 installation. I cleared logs before to go hibernate state to see what happens. Only one error was there from Bonjour Service and some warnings. So I disabled the Bonjour but it was not the solution. And what I mean with 'slow' is that fresh boot take usually longer as coming back from hibernate state.

Comment: Where should I upload the files?

Comment: Doesn't matter, [2shared](http://www.2shared.com/)?