# Blue screens and sporadic hanging - fault of the SSD?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, bsod

I am having issues with a two-month old build. The system was stable, then I bought the SSD and put my OS onto it. Now it will sporadically hang (I can move the mouse cursor sometimes, other times not) and wake up after a minute or two, but usually it will hang for about a minute and then crash (BSOD).

The odd thing is I can't just hit the reset switch, because the SSD won't show up in the boot options until I actually turn the machine off and on again.

On top of all this, I am sporadically getting pretty sluggish performance, mainly in the form of unresponsive apps. First one app will stop responding and then slowly all of them will stop responding. Then all I can do is alt-tab and move the mouse.

Event viewer gives me after the BSODs:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Date:          31/10/2011 4:29:53 PM
Event ID:      41
Task Category: (63)
Level:         Critical
Keywords:      (2)
User:          SYSTEM
Description:
The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.
```

I have the following config:

```
Operating System
        MS Windows 7 64-bit SP1
CPU
        Intel Core i7 2600  @ 3.40GHz   57 °C
        Sandy Bridge 32nm Technology
RAM
        8.00 GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 802MHz (11-11-11-28)
Motherboard
        ASUSTeK Computer INC. P8Z68-V (LGA1155) 60 °C
Graphics
        SMBX2450 (1920x1080@60Hz)
        SyncMaster (1920x1080@60Hz)
        AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series (ASUStek Computer Inc)    52 °C
Hard Drives
        117GB Corsair Force 3 SSD (SATA-SSD)    128 °C
        977GB Seagate ST31000528AS (SATA)   31 °C
        977GB Western Digital WDC WD1001FALS-00J7B1 (SATA)  42 °C
        1954GB Seagate ST32000542AS (SATA)  32 °C
        625GB Western Digital WDC WD6400AAKS-65A7B0 (SATA)  38 °C
Audio
        E-MU USB-Audio/MIDI 1.0 Device
```

This is pretty infuriating. Do you have any ideas? I feel like the SSD is letting me down here, should I send it back and get a new one? To be honest I haven't noticed a significant difference between the SSD and an HDD (though maybe that is the effect of rose-coloured glasses, since this drive has been such a hassle since I installed it).

Thanks for any insight you may be able to provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known problem with SSDs with firmware prior to 17th Oct 2011, that have a Sandforce controller.

**Answer: Update your SSD firmware.**

See this post in particular about the Corsair Force 3 SSD

> http://forum.corsair.com/forums/showthread.php?t=100162

Also see the answer to this question for more details as to what was going on, the same issue was present on the OCZ Vertex 3 drives.

> [Vertex 3 with Asus P8P67 Pro (B3) locks up](https://superuser.com/questions/326379/vertex-3-with-asus-p8p67-pro-b3-locks-up/334982#334982)

Comment: Thanks dude this is awesome. Gonna update right away! :D

Answer (score 1):

Given that [this military SSD](http://www.storagesearch.com/ssd-34.html) is designed for -55°C to +125°C, i would look into the 128 °C reported by your system.

Comment: there's no onboard sensor on the corsair force - 128 degrees is what is reported if there is no sensor. This is the official word from Corsair support. I was worried about that too! :D